# How to get the current category with custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, templates, page-template, categories

If I go to:
domain.example/category/skydancers-en-blikvangers/ I want to get all the posts in the current category for skydancers-en-blikvangers, I know I can hard code the category but this needs to be a dynamic template. So if I go to category/other-category that needs to work as well. 
Category.php:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2><?php _e( 'Posts for' ); single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Loop.php:

```
<!-- article -->
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <!-- post thumbnail -->
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- /post thumbnail -->

    <!-- post title -->
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    <!-- /post title -->

    <!-- post details -->
    <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
    <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'product' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
    <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
    <!-- /post details -->

    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

</article>
<!-- /article -->
```

```
<!-- article -->
<article>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
</article>
<!-- /article -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good basic technique to go from specifics to more general context is to look at the calls you already have.

You already call `single_cat_title()`, which somehow *knows* current category, right? If you look inside you will see it passes call to `single_term_title()`. And how does *that* one in turn knows?

```
$term = get_queried_object();
```

So there is your way to get to the full category object when on category archive page.

Still it's a little unclear from your code example what do you want to do with "all" posts. If you want to display all posts, in a context that *already* does appropriate query, you should be properly modifying main query via `pre_get_post` or such. It shouldn't be done in template for performance and compatibility reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try it in a few hours. The idea is that i want to show al the posts that are inside that category. Like a catelogus. I have a custom post type product, with product categories. So if i go to /category/pc i want to display al the pc's, then if you click on a pc. I want to go to the product page :)